# Remove all items in mdfind

Tags: terminal

How would I remove all of the items returned by mdfind? For example, I want to remove all files relating to "MacLaunchpad", so I did

```
mdfind "MacLaunchpad"
```

Which returned

```
/private/var/db/receipts/o.t.maclaunchpad.postflight.pkg.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/o.t.maclaunchpad.maclaunchpad.pkg.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/o.t.maclaunchpad.postflight.pkg.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/o.t.maclaunchpad.launchpad.pkg.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/o.t.maclaunchpad.launchpad.pkg.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/o.t.maclaunchpad.maclaunchpad.pkg.bom
```

I wish to remove all of these files; how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two ways for this

- `rm $(mdfind "MacLaunchpad")`
- `mdfind "MacLaunchpad" | xargs rm`

---

If you expect the resulting file/path names to contain spaces and other surprises use

```
mdfind -0 "MacLaunchpad" | xargs -0 rm --
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not general enough to handle spaces in the file names/paths. Is there a modification that can handle that?

Comment: @RoG Yes there is, see updated answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Great! Is there a trick to get this to work with grep (e.g. a `grep --null py$` or similar) between the two commands?

Comment: @RoG Not directly, you probably need to execute something like `grep pattern {} && rm -- {}` through `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that there is a `-onlyin /path/to/use` parameter to mdfind which helps a lot, even if it is not as fully general as using grep.

Comment: @RoG If you want to `grep` within files: `mdfind -0 "MacLaunchpad" | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c '[ -f "$1" ] && grep -q PATTERN -- "$1" && rm -- "$1"' sh`

Comment: @RoG and if you want to `grep` the file names: `mdfind -0 "MacLaunchpad" |  xargs -0 -n 1 bash -c '[[ -f "$1" && "$1" = *PATTERN* ]] && rm -- "$1"' bash`

Comment: If you need to remove a package receipt then you probably should use- `pkgutil --forget <package_id>`